# Web Sphere Application Server Logs

Tags: websphere-7, websphere-6.1

What are the different "log files" available in Web Sphere Application Server?
What is the use of "trace.log" file?
What are the different "log levels" available in Web Sphere Application Server?
Where can I find "process ID" in Web Sphere Application Server?
Can you please Suggest a Manual on Web Sphere Application Server v6.1,7.0?

Comment: it is recommended to dedicate each Stackoverflow question to exactly one actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You surely only need the System.Out files of the application server profile you're using, there is an activity.log file i think but thats mostly for IBM support IIRC.

The trace.log file is for when you enable JVM Tracing through the WAS Console for the different packages running on the app server.

The log levels are the standard JVM log levels.
    FATAL
    ERROR
    WARN
    INFO (Default)
    DEBUG
    TRACE

Websphere Application Server PID can be found through the management console, or by a quick commands like "ps -ef | grep WebSphere" (I tend to grep by the product folder name, and if you're running on a cluster enviroment will bring you the nodes and the deployment manager)

As for a manual, "Pro WebSphere Application Server Internals" is a good choice, and once you get the feel of the product the infocenter has most of what you may need.

Answer (score 1):

1. The log files are: SystemOut.log (info and above logging, System.out), SystemErr.log (System.err), trace.log (below info logging), native_stdout.log (JVM stdout), native_stderr.log (JVM stderr).  The native_* files are OS-level stream redirection, before WAS logging has replaced System.out/.err.
2. The trace.log file is created when the trace specification includes a level lower than logging.  It is primarily intended for service (PMRs) since it includes internal class and method names that have little meaning to people outside IBM, though there are some trace strings that might be useful.
3. See the [Tracing and logging configuration](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rtrb_enabletrc.html) topic in the InfoCenter.
4. The PID is stored in PROFILE_HOME/logs/SERVER/SERVER.pid.
5. I have no specific recommendation, though I would suggest looking at [WebSphere Redbooks](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/portals/websphere).  For example:

   - [WebSphere Application Server V7: Concepts, Planning and Design](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247708.html?Open)
   - [WebSphere Application Server V7 Administration and Configuration Guide](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247615.html?Open)
   - [WebSphere Application Server V7: Packaging Applications for Deployment](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4582.html?Open)
   - [WebSphere Application Server V7: Deploying Applications](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4583.html?Open)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there are two log files System.out and System.err.
For logging System.out is used..
You can change log levels by running admin console--troubleshooting---logging and tracing
different log levels are info,debug,fine,finer,finest,warn